# Want to identify lines with same value in column 3 and group them on output

Tags: python, python-3.x

Want to do this without using panda because it made the pyinstaller .exe file 74MB instead of 7.7MB and it also takes about 10x time to compile and it is slower when the .exe runs.

I have a .csv file like this, sorted on the [3] column (Assuming columns start at [0]):

```
Class,USB3,10,25,Y
Class,PCIE_CLK,8,31,Y
Class,PCIE_RX,8,31,Y
Class,PCIE_TX,8,31,Y
Class,PCIE_TX_C,8,31,Y
Class,DDR4_B0,3.20,38,Y
Class,DDR4_B1,3.20,38,Y
Class,DDR4_B2,3.20,38,Y
Class,DDR4_B3,3.20,38,Y
Class,DDR4_ADDR,3.20,39,Y
Class,DDR4_0,3.20,39,Y
Class,DDR4_1,3.20,39,Y
Class,DDR4_2,3.20,39,Y
Class,DDR4_3,3.20,39,Y
```

I want to identify and group the lines that have the same value in the [3] column.
Ultimately, the output would look like this:

```
25,USB3
31,PCIE_CLK or PCIE_RX or PCIE_RX or PCIE_TX or PCIE_TX_C
38,DDR4_B0 or DDR4_B1 or DDR4_B2 or DDR4_B3
39,DDR4_0 or DDR4_1 or DDR4_2 or DDR4_3
```

I really don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`.

```
import csv, itertools
with open("data.csv") as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f))
    key = lambda row: row[3]
    data = sorted(data, key=key) # if not already sorted by same key
    groups = itertools.groupby(data, key=key)
    for k, grp in groups:
        print(k, *(g[1] for g in grp))
```

Output:

```
25 USB3
31 PCIE_CLK PCIE_RX PCIE_TX PCIE_TX_C
38 DDR4_B0 DDR4_B1 DDR4_B2 DDR4_B3
39 DDR4_ADDR DDR4_0 DDR4_1 DDR4_2 DDR4_3
```

Comment: Ok, now I am trying to write this to a csv file and am stumped again. Sorry for being such a rookie.

Comment: @CPMAN How should the resulting CSV file be structured? In CSV, all the rows should have the same number of columns, so should the different items be all in one row, as a string or similar?

Comment: Good point. How about just writing it to a text file so it looks like the print output.

Comment: @CPMAN For this, you can just pipe the result to a text file: `python3 your_script.py > output.txt`. Or use another `with open("output.txt", "w") as f` and then `f.write(...)` to write to that file.

Comment: I have tried the f.write(...) method, but I don't know what to put in the "..." part. Sigh. I must look like a real dummy. I am writing a lot of .csv and .txt files as needed in other parts of the program, but in this case working with the groupby, I cannot figure out what to write. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @CPMAN Well, just write what you want to write. You can't use `*(...)` as in `print`, so maybe something like `f.write(k + ',' + ' or '.join(g[1] for g in grp))`?

Comment: Finally I am using this:         print((k,*(g[1] for g in grp)), file=open('ACG_Data/AD_ClassTriggerNetGroups.txt', 'a+'))

Comment: Your method is working great but now I want to add the [2] column from the input file as well, but I don't know how to do it. I have tried this    print((k + ',{},' + ' or '.join(g[1] for g in grp)).format(row[2]), file=open('test.csv', 'a+'))    but the output is always the same number rather than changing it like [2] varies in the input file.  I suspect at this point the group function isn't iterating through the input file the same way.